# Building a mask out of a selection of days of week (MTWTFSS) to find whether a specific day matches via basic operators only

Tags: algorithm, mask, dayofweek

Given a selection of days of week, I need to know whether a specific day is matching the selection.

For example, given:

```
enum DayOfWeek {
    MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN
}
```

And the following selection:

```
List<DayOfWeek> selection = List.of(MON, WED);
```

If a given day's day of week is `MON` or `WED`, then it should match, otherwise it shouldn't.

A straightforward approach:

```
boolean match = selection.contains(day.getDayOfWeek());
```

I'm wondering whether there's a way to build a mask out of the selection, and finding whether a given day matches only with basic operators (`+ - * / % AND OR NOT EQ LT LTE GT GTE`, no bitwise operators allowed).

For instance, given that same selection:

```
int mask = 1010000; // just an example of a mask, can be any other
```

Then:

```
boolean match = fn(mask, day.getDayOfWeek());
```

Could such a `mask` exist so that `fn` can be written with basic operators only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a boolean approach, take some prime numbers

```
MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN
2,   3,   5,   7,   11,   13,  17
```

The mask is composed of the product of selected day, e.g `(MON, WED) -> 2*5 = 10`

The dayOfWeek matches iff it divides the mask (idem `mask % dayOfWeek === 0`)

e.g

- `TUE -> 3, mask % 3 != 0`, not in selection
- `MON -> 2, mask % 2 === 0`, in selection

Comment: you are welcome @sp00m, beware of int overflow they come quickly with this method though :(